# How to check if files are different before copying and overwriting?

Tags: shell-script, backup

I use a little script that copy (using `cp`) a list of config files to another device. I wonder how to quickly check whether the files were modified since last time before doing it and exhausting the device for nothing.

Comment: Use `rsync`, not `cp`...

Comment: "exhausting the device"?

Comment: @Rahul do you know what is best between `rsync` and `cp -u` ?

Comment: cp -u only looks at the timestamp. rsync looks at the contents.

Comment: @pjc50 `rsync` doesn't look at the content unless the timestamps are different and the copy is remote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have a `config` directory locally that corresponds to a `config` directory on your device, and that you only make changes locally before syncing them to the device, then `rsync` is a good tool to perform the sync.

To sync the local directory to the device's directory:

```
$ rsync -av config/ someuser@device.address:path/to/config/
```

To delete files on the device that are not any longer present in the local `config` directory, add the `--delete` flag to `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -av --delete config/ someuser@device.address:path/to/config/
```

Swap `config/` and `someuser@device.address:path/to/config/` to instead back up the `config` directory from the device to a local directory (it was slightly unclear what direction you wanted to go in the question).

Comment: Is there a way to activate verbose mode for files only (not folder) ?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs Not that I'm aware of, but you could pipe the output through `grep -v '/$'` to filter out any line containing a slash at the end...

Comment: @ChiseledAbs Look for `--info` and `--out-format` in `rsync` manual.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I had a look at those (in the `rsyncd.conf` manual), but couldn't easily find a way to repress the output of directories specifically.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ! diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null 2>&1;
then

  echo "Files are changed"

else

  echo "Files not changed"

fi
```

Comment: No, use `cmp -s` instead. It's made to be used for this is scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `diff/cmp` is good, but in case of very big files comparing may take a while. More faster ways are comparing timestamps via `stat` or comparing checksums via `md5sum`

Comment: `cmp` will stop at the first diff. I find it hard to believe that's slower than calculating an MD5 digest for two files.

Comment: Comparing checksums is faster only when the two files are on different machines and the network is the bottleneck.